# System.Data.SqlXml Version 2 not installed on system

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, msxml

One of our build agent servers does not have System.Data.SqlXml Version=2.0.0.0 under C:\Windows\assembly but every other machine we have does. Unfortunately this causes nunit-summary.exe on that box to fail with:

> EXEC Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlXml,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>       error MSB3073: The command ""../tools/nunit-summary.exe" artifacts/*Test*_*.xml" exited with code -1.

I tried installing MSXML 4 to no avail. I have not been able to figure out how to install version 2, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions.

a) In the project, expand references to find the reference to the library. Go to properies and set `Copy Local` to be `True`. The .dll will then be included in the bin folder when the project is built.

b) Install SQLXML from Microsoft (this is different to MSXML which you tried). Details about the library (including the download link) are available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml/what-s-new-in-sqlxml-4-0-sp1

Comment: Installing SQLXML 4 did not work unfortunately, nunit-summary is an exe and requires version 2. I did some more research and it looks like SQLXML 2.0 is from sql server 2000, and it requires sql server 2000 client tools. I think the solution is to use the latest nunit console and remove nunit-summary from our build.